# How to read input through a csv file and write the output in an output file in power shell script?

Tags: powershell, file, input, configuration

[image: Sharing the screenshot of input csv file][[image: Sharing the screenshot of input csv file]]This is the powershell script to get the selected services status of servers,where list of servers are given through input csv file and the status of those server should be stored in an output file.

-----------Below is the script----------

```
$Servers = Get-Content "C:\temp\input.csv"
$Log = @()
foreach($Server in $Servers)
{
    $Services = Get-Service *HRRA*, "SQL Server Reporting Services" -ComputerName $COMPUTERNAME
    foreach ($Service in $Services)
    {
    $properties = @(
                  @{n='ServiceName';e={$Service.Name}}
                  @{n='Status';e={$Service.Status}}
                  @{n='ServerName';e={$Server}}
                  )
    $Log += "" | select $properties
    }

}
$Log  | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File "D:\temp\test.txt" -Force
```

------------------------------------New Script----------------------------------

```
$Computers = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\Input.csv"
#$mailboxdata =  Get-Service *HRRA*,"SQL Server Reporting Services" -ComputerName $ComputerName| select machinename,name, status | sort machinename | 
#format-table -AutoSize |Out-File "D:\Temp\RRR.txt"
#LogWrite "$ComputerName"
foreach($row in $computers)
{
{
Add-Content -Path D:\Temp\SSRS.txt -Value $mailboxdata }
Get-Content -Path D:\Temp\SSRS.txt  
                 $ComputerName= $row.ComputerName;
$mailboxdata =  Get-Service *HRRA*,"SQL Server Reporting Services" -ComputerName $ComputerName| select machinename,name, status | sort machinename | 
format-table -AutoSize |Out-File "D:\Temp\SSR.txt"
$fromaddress = "Reporting.Services@accenture.com" 
$toaddress = "aditi.m.singh@accenture.Com"
#$toaddress1 = "s.ab.balakrishnan@accenture.com"
$Subject = "SSRS Services Status" 
$body = "Please find attached - test"
$attachment = "D:\Temp\SSR.txt" 
$smtpserver = "AMRINT.SMTP.ACCENTURE.COM"
$message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$message.From = $fromaddress 
$message.To.Add($toaddress)
#$message.To.Add($toaddress1)
$message.IsBodyHtml = $True 
$message.Subject = $Subject 
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment) 
$message.Attachments.Add($attach) 
$message.body = $body 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver) 
$smtp.Send($message)
```

}

```
If i am running the script with static value its giving me output for both the servers---Below is the script----
Get-Service *HRRA*,"SQL Server Reporting Services" -ComputerName VW118627, VW118623 | select name, status, machinename | sort machinename | format-table -AutoSize |
Out-File "D:\Temp\Report.txt"
```

[image: This is the output i am getting after giving server name as static values]

Comment: Don't screenshot code, copy and paste it. Also please clarify what your issue is?

Comment: The issue is that out of two servers in input file i am getting service status for only one server.

Comment: $Computers = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\Input.csv"
$mailboxdata =  Get-Service *HRRA*,"SQL Server Reporting Services" -ComputerName $ComputerName| select machinename,name, status | sort machinename | 
format-table -AutoSize |Out-File "D:\Temp\RRR.txt"
LogWrite "$ComputerName"
foreach($row in $computers)
{
{
Add-Content -Path D:\Temp\RRR.txt -Value $mailboxdata }

Comment: this is the snippet of code

Comment: i am passing a csv file as input like ComputerName

Comment: under computer name two servers are mentioned and then passing it inside mailbox data but it reading for only the second server under Heading ComputerName

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61226082/edit) your question and enter the asked for information there as [formatted text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189). Simply adding stuff incomments is unreadable

Comment: Hi @Theo i have formatted the code and edited the question.Please do the needfull i am badly stuck with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot, I can see the input csv is really a **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues file. For these, you use the `Import-Csv` cmdlet to retrieve an array of computer names from the file.

```
$outputFile = "D:\temp\test.csv"

# make sure the field name matches what is in the CSV header
$Servers = (Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\input.csv").ComputerName  

$Log = foreach($Server in $Servers) {
    # add a test to see if we can reach the server
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Get-Service -Name *HRRA*, "SQL Server Reporting Services" -ComputerName $Server | 
        Select-Object @{Name = 'MachineName'; Expression = {$Server}},
                      @{Name = 'ServiceName'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                      @{Name = 'Status';      Expression = {$_.Status}}
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Server '$Server' is unreachable"
    }
}

# if you want the log sorted, do
$Log = $Log | Sort-Object MachineName

# output on screen
$Log | Format-Table -AutoSize 

# output to CSV file
$Log | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -Force -NoTypeInformation

# mail the output csv file using Send-MailMessage
# collect the parameters in a hashtable
$mailParams = @{
    SmtpServer  = "AMRINT.SMTP.ACCENTURE.COM"
    From        = "Reporting.Services@accenture.com"
    To          = "aditi.m.singh@accenture.com"
    Subject     = "SSRS Services Status"
    Body        = "Please find attached - test"
    BodyAsHtml  = $true
    Attachments = $outputFile
    # add other parameters if needed
    # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage
} 
# use 'splatting' to send the email 
# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting
Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

<sup>P.S. The `Format-Table` cmdlet is for displaying the object(s) **on screen only**.</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211814/discussion-on-answer-by-theo-how-to-read-input-through-a-csv-file-and-write-the).